# Error installing Java on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, java

I get this error almost when installation is finished:

```
/proc is not mounted; some java apps may fail
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Ignoring error generating classes.jsa
```

Why is this?

I just entered `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts`

Is there something I must do first? What is Proc?

If you need more input let me know. Thanks

**EDIT**

Is there a way to test if the java machine works on the ubuntu server?
Example, put a file which uses Java and then access it via the website to see if the server supports java.

Note: I have windows xp, using PuTTY to communicate with my Server, and on my own computer I have java installed also, so thats a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure your system has /proc  it's a virtual filesystem used to access/config things relating to the kernel & system info.

how to check that java is working?  compile something simple like [hello world](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) & try to run it!

Comment: ok, check my update also please.

Comment: So the first line is an error you can probably ignore, but 'Could not reserve enough space for object heap' sounds serious!
how much free RAM does the server have? do you have swap? is this a VPS?

Comment: Actually, just checked and might be a RAM problem yes... Do you know of any way to stop or disable java, to check how much free ram there is without java activated?

Comment: 'installing' java the way you have will not take up any RAM, just disk space. It's not a service, just a compiler with some libraries.